# Why Are My Htaccess Redirects Not Working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Good Morning,

**TL;DR:** The issue with some of these redirects are they are just going to the front page and not going to the specific page I'm trying to get them to redirect to. How to solve this issue?

**What has been done so far:**

I recently began working for a company who needs to redirect many URLs to specific pages within their website. The URLs are managed by Godaddy and the site is hosted by Siteground. I tried already to redirect them from Godaddy using domain forwarding, but was told by a former consultant who worked with this company that she was getting security errors after I did that.

So I removed all of my redirects out of godaddy. I then parked all of the domains on siteground and switched all of the name servers to siteground's name servers. After that, I turned on SSL encryption for all of the URLs and used the SG optimizer wordpress plugin (which the company already had installed) to enforce SSL to avoid any security issues.

I then went to edit the htaccess file. (Which I will share at the bottom of my post)

**The issue with some of these redirects are they are just going to the front page and not going to the specific page I'm trying to get them to redirect to. How to solve this issue?**

**Note:** lines 0 - 102 are lines I created last night. Anything below line 102 was pre-existing and I just left them in there.

```
RedirectPermanent https://arsondetection.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent http://arsondetection.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent https://arsondetective.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent http://arsondetective.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent https://emergencylandingzone.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/emergency-landing-zone-kit/
RedirectPermanent http://emergencylandingzone.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/emergency-landing-zone-kit/
RedirectPermanent https://fallsuspension.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/
RedirectPermanent http://fallsuspension.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/
RedirectPermanent https://firefighterpassalarms.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent http://firefighterpassalarms.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent https://firepassalarms.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent http://firepassalarms.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent https://flarelite.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/flare-lites/
RedirectPermanent http://flarelite.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/flare-lites/
RedirectPermanent https://glowbaton.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/glow-batons/
RedirectPermanent http://glowbaton.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/glow-batons/
RedirectPermanent https://gracearson.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent http://gracearson.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectPermanent https://graceconnectedsafety.com https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://graceconnectedsafety.com http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://gracefallsafety.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/
RedirectPermanent http://gracefallsafety.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/
RedirectPermanent https://gracefiregroundcontrol.com https://www.graceindustries.com/in-command-full-crew-3/
RedirectPermanent http://gracefiregroundcontrol.com http://www.graceindustries.com/in-command-full-crew-3/
RedirectPermanent https://gracefirekit.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/in-command-first-in/
RedirectPermanent http://gracefirekit.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/in-command-first-in/
RedirectPermanent https://gracefirepass.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent http://gracefirepass.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/
RedirectPermanent https://gracefirezoneaccountability.com https://www.graceindustries.com/in-command-full-crew-3/
RedirectPermanent http://gracefirezoneaccountability.com http://www.graceindustries.com/in-command-full-crew-3/
RedirectPermanent https://graceglobalfire.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/international/
RedirectPermanent http://graceglobalfire.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/international/
RedirectPermanent https://graceindustries.biz https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://graceindustries.biz http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://graceindustries.net https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://graceindustries.net http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://graceindustries.us https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://graceindustries.us http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://graceindustriesnews.com https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://graceindustriesnews.com http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://graceloneworker.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-    worker-safety/
RedirectPermanent http://graceloneworker.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/
RedirectPermanent https://gracemandownsystems.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/
RedirectPermanent http://gracemandownsystems.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/
RedirectPermanent https://gracemobileloneworker.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/mobile/
RedirectPermanent http://gracemobileloneworker.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/mobile/
RedirectPermanent https://gracenfpapassalarm.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://gracenfpapassalarm.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://gracepassalarm.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://gracepassalarm.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://gracesales.com https://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent http://gracesales.com http://graceindustries.com
RedirectPermanent https://gracesuperpass4.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://gracesuperpass4.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://gracetpass.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/tpass-3-am-buddy-system/
RedirectPermanent http://gracetpass.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/tpass-3-am-buddy-system/
RedirectPermanent https://gracetpass5.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/tpass-5/
RedirectPermanent http://gracetpass5.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/tpass-5/
RedirectPermanent https://gracetpassalarm.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/tpass-3-am-buddy-system/
RedirectPermanent http://gracetpassalarm.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/tpass-3-am-buddy-system/
RedirectPermanent https://gracewildfire.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/wildlands/
RedirectPermanent http://gracewildfire.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/wildlands/
RedirectPermanent https://graceworkforce.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/workforce/
RedirectPermanent http://graceworkforce.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/workforce/
RedirectPermanent https://litesafety.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://litesafety.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://litetrackers.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/lite-trackers/
RedirectPermanent https://litetrackers.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/lite-trackers/
RedirectPermanent https://nfpapass.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://nfpapass.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://nfpastandalonepass.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/superpass-5/
RedirectPermanent http://nfpastandalonepass.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/superpass-5/
RedirectPermanent https://passalarms.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://passlarms.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://passdevice.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://passdevice.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://rescuelites.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://rescuelites.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent https://safetylitehq.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://safetylitehq.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent https://safetyliteshop.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://safetyliteshop.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent https://safetylitestore.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent http://safetylitestore.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/
RedirectPermanent https://superpass2.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/superpass-2/
RedirectPermanent http://superpass2.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/superpass-2/
RedirectPermanent https://superpass3.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/superpass-2/
RedirectPermanent http://superpass3.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/superpass-2/
RedirectPermanent https://superpass5.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/superpass-5/
RedirectPermanent http://superpass5.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/superpass-5/
RedirectPermanent https://superpassalarms.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://superpassalarms.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://superpasshq.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://superpasshq.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://superpassstore.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://superpassstore.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://superpassworld.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent http://superpassworld.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/pass/
RedirectPermanent https://tpass5.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/tpass-5/
RedirectPermanent http://tpass5.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/tpass-5/
RedirectPermanent https://workforcefallarrest.com https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/
RedirectPermanent http://workforcefallarrest.com http://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/

RedirectMatch 301 /BuddyPackage.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/BuddyPackage.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /SupervisorWeb.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/SupervisorWeb.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /MS2000X.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/MS2000X.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /LW2017.pdf http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/LW2019.pdf
RedirectMatch 301 /AtlasJoe.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/AtlasJoe.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /AtlasBuddy.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/AtlasBuddy.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /AtlasSupervisor.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/AtlasSupervisor.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /AtlasMS2000X.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/AtlasMS2000X.mp4
RedirectMatch 301 /JoeWEB.mp4 http://www.graceindustries.info/sales/JoeWEB.mp4

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arsondetection.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.arsondetection.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/     [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gracefirefighter.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gracefirefighter.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/ [L,R=301,NC]
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^graceloneworker.com [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.graceloneworker.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gracewildfire.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gracewildfire.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/wildlands/     [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gracefallsafety.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gracefallsafety.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/fall-arrest-safety/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^superpass2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.superpass2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/superpass-2/ [L,R=301,NC]

RedirectMatch 301 /product/in-command-first-in-incident-command-monitor/     https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/tpass-accountability/in-command-first-in-full-crew/
RedirectMatch 301 /product/loneworker-safety-monitoring-system/ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/fixed-facility/sms-safety-monitoring-evac-system/
RedirectMatch 301 /product/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/arson-hydrocarbon-detection/
RedirectMatch 301 /product/safety-lights/ https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/personal-safety-lights/

#This Apache config file was created by Duplicator Installer on 2020-08-02 00:36:58.
#The original can be found in archived file with the name .htaccess__[HASH]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do mention sample of URLs which ones are not working which will give us better understanding of your question.

Comment: Thank you, yes for example www.GraceLoneWorker.com is supposed to go to https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/lone-worker-safety/ but instead it only goes as far as www.graceindustries.com - meanwhile www.GraceFireFighter.com goes to https://www.graceindustries.com/safety-products/firefighter/ as expected.

Comment: FYI: That whole first block of RedirectPermanent directives there should achieve absolutely nothing to begin with. The directive matches on the _URL path_, not full absolute URLs including protocol and host name.

Comment: The definition of the `RedirectPermanent` directive is clearly documented. I suggest you actually _read_ the documentation of the tool you use.

Comment: Thank you and where can I find this documentation? And if that's not the correct directive, then what directive should I use?